# Вопрос по косвенной речи

Tags: пунктуация

Есть предложение от лица автора - женщины, которая, видимо, имеет в виду фразу, сказанную ей кем-то. Оформлено оно было так:

Но вот сейчас передо мной все три вышедших номера (в 4-х томах) за первое полугодие 2014 года, и можно ответить редакции и коллегам-читателям: что хорошего и что тревожного на ваш, сударыня, взгляд на арматурном небосклоне.

Мне кажется, здесь нужно оформить так:

Но вот сейчас передо мной все три вышедших номера (в 4-х томах) за первое полугодие 2014 года, и можно ответить редакции и коллегам-читателям «что хорошего и что тревожного на ваш, сударыня, взгляд на арматурном небосклоне».

Есть у кого-нибудь какие-нибудь мнения по этому поводу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваш вариант соединил прямую и косвенную речь,что недопустимо. Если Вы используете косвенную речь, она должна быть в виде сложноподчинённого предложения от третьего лица, а Вы сохранили обращение от первого лица.Тогда уж должно быть так: Но вот сейчас передо мной все три вышедших номера (в 4-х томах) за первое полугодие 2014 года, и можно ответить редакции и коллегам-читателям, «что хорошего и что тревожного... на арматурном небосклоне». Исходный вариант от первого лица должен быть оформлен всё-таки как предложение с прямой речью, а здесь - как несобственно прямая речь, когда неизвестно, кому цитата принадлежит. Следовало бы добавить слово "вопрос" и оформить так: Но вот сейчас передо мной все три вышедших номера (в 4-х томах) за первое полугодие 2014 года, и можно ответить редакции и коллегам-читателям на вопрос: "Что хорошего и что тревожного на ваш, сударыня, взгляд на арматурном небосклоне?"

Comment: Спасибо большое за такое развернутое объяснение. Действительно, последний вариант намного лучше и ведь не хватало всего одного слова...

Answer (score 0):

1. Не "в 4-х томах", а "в 4 томах".
2. Не "Все три вышедших номера за первое полугодие 2014 года", а "все три номера, вышедших за первое полугодие 2014 года".